# Is it possible to encode multiple data in a QR code?

Tags: qr-code

I have a classifieds webapp for our student union and want to create printable versions of the different ads, that students can print and distribute on the campus. To get further information, people should be able to read a QR code from the printout with their smartphone.

The question is: Can I encode both the phone number to call for the ad and the URL of the website in the QR code at the same time, so that people can scan the code and then select if they want to call the person or open the website of the ad?

I was thinking about using a vcard, but that would add that otherwise useless information to the peoples contacts list. Is there something like CSV data that Android correctly reads to achieve this? (And preferably iPhones, too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.

VCard is fine, it would enable other QR readers to parse it correctly - so your QR would be up to standard.

You wouldn't have to implement full [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) though, just the basic TEL, and URL fields.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be really the simple answer. :-)

Comment: Indeed, just plug in the contact info and URL here to generate the proper vCard (or MECARD) encoding: http://zxing.appspot.com/generator